# Transform Text To Another Text On Mouse Hover

Tags: jquery, html

How can i make my actual text transform into another text when the user hovers his/her mouse on top of the original text. I have provided the HTML code below. Any feedback is much appreciated!

```
<a href="#" class="btn_action_1">
    <span>Justice League</span>
<i class="ico_arrow"></i>
</a>
```

EX: I have a text called ABC. When user points mouse on ABC, the element will transform into DEF. Got my point?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i think i must place something like this: onmouseover='DEF';
   onmouseout='ABC';>

Comment: That's not how it works, you include javascript in those events. You can use CSS's :hover or some simple javascript

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Stack Overlow is extremely complicated, especially for first-time users. It has lots of restrictions. Comments for instance do not always show up in my inbox, so i cannot be certain who replied and who didn't. I have to manually check from time to time by refreshing the page and scrolling down to see if someone answered or not. By the way, I also answered your question where i said that my answered was solved. I deleted it bz it turned out that it still did not solve my original question completely as I previously thought it did.

Comment: and concerning the voting, it seems like SO rejects voting on any post because i'm still new to the platform. I think i must earn some reputation in order to vote for answers. don't know if that's true. and that's another example of how complicated and sophisticated this platorm is.

Comment: the only good part though why I use it is primarily because it's free to post and get answers. unlike other websites who charge for a fee based on time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css` `:hover`, `:before`, `content`

```css
a span:not(:hover):before {
  content: "ABC";
}
a span:hover:before {
  content: "DEF";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn_action_1">
    <span></span>
<i class="ico_arrow"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: THX SO MUCH @guest271314. But should i place this in CSS or HTML?

Comment: @k4r1 The approach utilizes `css`

Comment: ":not(:hover):before" It's very nice. Didn't know about that functionality

Comment: @guest271314. i have one more question. if i have several texts that i need to transform while user mouseovers, should i leave the " " empty without writing any text? so that i only insert text in HTML?

Comment: @k4r1 _"if i have several texts that i need to transform while user mouseovers, should i leave the " " empty without writing any text? so that i only insert text in HTML?"_ Not certain what you mean?

Comment: ok will try to be more clearer. i mean like i have on my live website several HTML buttons that states under each product "View Details". I have placed the same button under every single product on my website. What I'm trying to achieve is when the user hovers his/her mouse on top of any of those buttons, they will see another text, which supposedly should be the PRODUCT NAME. So if i leave the quotations empty in the CSS like this: " " with no text, that means that i can modify the text that i want to change in the HTML.

Comment: because if i change it in the CSS, the text that will appear on hover will display the same FOR ALL OF MY BUTTONS!

Comment: You can use unique `id` or `data-*` attribute at each element which would be hovered, use the unique selector for each element, which should provide unique text for each element when hovered

Comment: ok that's good, but how would that sum up with the original code i've provided at the vry beginning? i don't know where to place these attributes.

Comment: @k4r1  _"but how would that sum up with the original code i've provided at the vry beginning?"_ The original Question did not include description of multiple elements. _"i don't know where to place these attributes."_ at `html`

Comment: @guest271314 but this is the ONLY HTML CODE I HAVE!!! I did not cut anything out of it. what you're giving me is a partial answer!

Comment: @guest271314 i need to make it work for every button element, not for all of my button elements. that is what i was trying to tell you in my previous comments. the link in Plunker which you have provided allows the text that needs to be transformed apply to all of the buttons on my site, which is the opposite of what i want.

Comment: @k4r1 _"i need to make it work for every button element, not for all of my buttons."_ You did not include full `html` at Question; only one element is present at Question text. Again, you can set a unique `id` or `data-*` attribute at each element, then define unique  `:hover` for each unique element at `css` using same approach as demonstrated at Answer

Comment: and i'm quoting again: "@guest271314 but this is the ONLY HTML CODE I HAVE!!! I did not cut anything out of it. what you're giving me is a partial answer!" That is the only HTML I have. This code was purely taken from a website called "https://www.baamboostudio.com/" Did not touch anything, that I can guarantee you. So giving me pure attributes won't quite cut it or help much as they are pretty useless. You need to specify where these attributes should be placed in the HTML code to fully complete my answer.

Comment: i have also provided you with the CSS of this widget and you replied as follows: "Question should not be Answer". Don't know why you wrote that. Anyways, this is everything I've got to provide. I've given everything I have.

Comment: @k4r1 _" "Question should not be Answer". Don't know why you wrote that."_ The Question contents should be at actual Question. You provided an Answer for your own Question, instead of editing your original Question; unless your Answer actually answered your own original Question. _"Anyways, this is everything I've got to provide. I've given everything I have."_ You have only provided single set of elements for `:hover` to be applied to `<a href="#" class="btn_action_1">
    <span>Justice League</span>
<i class="ico_arrow"></i>
</a>`

Comment: @guest271314 correct each element must have a unique hover. you said that i must add a unique **id** or **data-*** attribute at each element. plz check out Luis's answer to my post at the bottom of this post, perhaps it can help you more identify to see what's missing.

Comment: If you want different `:hover` effect for different elements you can set an `id` or `data-*` attribute at each element, then set `css` to correspond to that specific eleiment. E.g., `html`: `<a href="#" class="btn_action_1" id="1">
    <span></span>
<i class="ico_arrow"></i>
</a>`, `css`: `a[id="1"] span:not(:hover):before {
  content: "ABC";
}
a[id="1"] span:hover:before {
  content: "DEF";
}`. Similarly `html`: `<a href="#" class="btn_action_1" id="2">`
, `css`: `a[id="2"] span:not(:hover):before {
  content: "GHI";
}a[id="2"] span:hover:before {
  content: "JKL";
}`

Comment: @k4r1 See http://plnkr.co/edit/6JtFhM4bvkiDAqQzMgBM?p=preview at version 2

Comment: Hi @guest271314. alright that is a wise answer! I can absolutely do that though my CSS will be very long because I have over 500 different buttons and so I'll have to give each a unique **id**. that will be a long process but well worth it. Thank you once again for keeping up and not abandoning. Much appreciated. (-:

Comment: yes, i saw the new link. that is what i want. i can do that with ease now. thx

Comment: @guest271314, i've check marked the question as Answered!

Comment: @guest271314, no it does not answer my question, so i left it greyed and unchecked. the only Answer that answered my question was yours, which I've marked green!

Answer (score 0):

There is the solution I made:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var text1 = "Justice League";
        var text2 = "Avengers";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".btn_action_1").mouseover(function(){
                $(".btn_action_1 span").html(text2);
            });

            $(".btn_action_1").mouseout(function(){                 
                $(".btn_action_1 span").html(text1);
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn_action_1">
        <span>Justice League</span>
        <i class="ico_arrow"></i>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Luis. Thx for the code. I tried it on my website, but unfortunately the name "Justice League" remained the same after hovering my mouse. It did not change to Avengers. )-;

Comment: Hi k4r1. You must have the jquery-3.1.0.min.js file on your website to work. Let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: hey @Luis, i have installed both versions of the "jquery-3.1.0.min.js" compressed and uncompressed on my website, and have included the HTML on my site, but still no avail. It just appears as Justice League even after hover. what should i do now?

Comment: there seems like there's something missing or wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using jQuery `hover`, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

You can change the html upon `mouseenter` and re-initialize it to old one upon `mouseleave`

Here is the live demo on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/magician03/v5goshLk/

Comment: i don't want to use jQuery. I prefer if it is HTML because i have many buttons with text inside which I'm intending to replace the text when users hovers mouse on top. So it should be like "View Details", and then when the users hovers his mouse, the text will change to the product's actual name.